# Trouble installing coffee script on my Macbook

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, installation

I tried install coffee-script through the following command:

```
npm -g install coffee-script
```

Then I got these errors,

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.6.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.6.2.tgz
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack:
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/cinker
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.24
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cinker/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Then I want to use npm in sudo mode to cover the previous installation, however, the terminal console warned again, in different words.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
/usr/local/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/bin/cake -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json assert-plus@0.1.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
```

When I execute coffee-script, it works. However, errors are seen when I run cake.

So my question is:
1. What's wrong with what I did on the installation?
2. Can I remove the coffee-script and install it again?
3. Is there any other methods to do this?(I tried homebrew, but failed)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of errors do you see when you run `cake`? It's normal to see "Cakefile not found". `cake` needs a Cakefile to run. See [cake documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#cake). The "no repository field" warnings are no problem. They just indiciate less than perfect package metadata.

Answer (score 1):

- As [suggested by Isaac](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm), you can do also this, and then install coffee as a global module:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

- Yes, you can remove coffee-script installation without any harm.
- Npm is a good way to install coffee, try to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

```
sudo npm -g install coffee-script
```

This will keep the /usr/local directory's security in tact, while at the same time providing users of the system -execute- permissions without the need to change ownership of /usr/local to one user.